How to exclude handled exceptions from being logged in ASP .NET Core (using NLog)
I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API hosted on an Azure App Service (Windows).
I am using NLog for logging, and Pomelo 8.0.2 for accessing an Azure database for MySql server.
Currently, the API is logging all exceptions, handled or not. I would like to know if it's possible to not log handled exceptions?
I will provide the classes I believe are pertinent below:
Program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

using NLog;
using NLog.Web;

using System;

[assembly: ApiConventionType(typeof(DefaultApiConventions))]

namespace PropWorx.API
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Logger logger = NLog.LogManager
                .Setup()
                .SetupExtensions(s => s.RegisterLayoutRenderer<NLogLayoutRenderer>("websiteDeploymentId"))
                .LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings()
                .GetCurrentClassLogger();

            // I'm attempting three ways here to turn off logging when the app is running in debug mode:
            // 1. The first line sets a value in the Global Diagnostics Context (GDC) of NLog.
            //    In the nlog.config file, I retrieve this value using the ${gdc:item=debugLogLevel} syntax.
            // 2. Directly sets a configuration variable in NLog's current configuration.
            //    In the nlog.config file, you would retrieve this value using the ${var:debugLogLevel} syntax.
            // 3. The third line sets a Global Threshold.
            //    Only logs that have the same or higher severity than this threshold will be logged.
            #if DEBUG
            NLog.GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("debugLogLevel", "Off"); 
            LogManager.Configuration.Variables["debugLogLevel"] =  "Off";
            NLog.LogManager.GlobalThreshold = NLog.LogLevel.Off;
            #else
            NLog.GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("debugLogLevel", "Warn");
            LogManager.Configuration.Variables["debugLogLevel"] = "Warn";
            NLog.LogManager.GlobalThreshold = NLog.LogLevel.Warn;
            #endif

            // Explicit refresh of Layouts and updates active Logger-objects
            LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();

            try
            {
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                logger.Error(exception, "Stopped program because of exception");
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                       .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                           {
                               webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                           })
                       .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                           {
                               logging.ClearProviders();
                               logging.AddConsole();
                               logging.AddDebug();
                               logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
                               logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
                           })
                      .UseNLog();  // NLog: setup NLog for Dependency injection        
        }
    }
}

nlog.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  autoReload="true"
  internalLogLevel="Info"
  throwExceptions="true"
  internalLogFile="${basedir}\logs\internal-nlog-AspNetCore.txt">

<!--debugLogLevel is being set in Program.cs depending on whether the app is running in debug mode or not-->
<variables name="debugLogLevel" value="${gdc:item=debugLogLevel:whenEmpty=Warn}" />

<!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
<extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget" />
</extensions>

<!-- the targets to write to -->
<targets>
    <target xsi:type="ApplicationInsightsTarget" name="aiTarget">
        <!-- <instrumentationKey>d1e109db-435f-434c-94be-d934ea201690</instrumentationKey> -->
        <instrumentationKey>14bd5b2b-3e4e-40fb-9d40-981c68e3be54</instrumentationKey>
        <!-- Only required if not using ApplicationInsights.config -->
        <contextproperty name="threadid" layout="${threadid}" />
        <!-- Can be repeated with more context -->
    </target>

    <!--Console Target for hosting lifetime messages to improve Docker / Visual Studio startup detection -->
    <target xsi:type="Console" name="lifetimeConsole" layout="${newline}${level:truncate=4:tolower=true}\: ${logger}[0]${newline}      ${message}${exception:format=tostring}" />

    <target name="db"
        xsi:type="Database"
        dbProvider="MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection, MySqlConnector"
        connectionString="${environment:variable=ConnectionStrings__LogDataContext}"
        commandType="StoredProcedure"
        commandText="`propworx_log`.`InsertLog`">
        <parameter name="machineName"    layout="${machinename}" />
        <parameter name="logged"         layout="${date}" />
        <parameter name="logLevel"       layout="${level}" />
        <parameter name="message"        layout="${message}" />
        <parameter name="logger"         layout="${logger}" />
        <parameter name="properties"     layout="${all-event-properties:separator=|}" />
        <parameter name="callsite"       layout="${callsite}" />
        <parameter name="exception"      layout="${exception:tostring}" />
        <parameter name="callsiteLineNumber"      layout="${callsite-linenumber}" />
        <parameter name="stackTrace"      layout="${stacktrace}" />
        <parameter name="websiteDeploymentId"      layout="${websiteDeploymentId}" />
        <parameter name="requestHeaders"      layout="${aspnet-request-headers}" />
        <parameter name="requestBody"      layout="${aspnet-request-posted-body}" />
        <parameter name="mvcAction"      layout="${aspnet-mvc-action}" />
        <parameter name="mvcController"      layout="${aspnet-mvc-controller}" />
        <parameter name="requestMethod"      layout="${aspnet-request-method}" />
        <parameter name="requestUrl"      layout="${aspnet-request-url}" />
        <parameter name="requestRouteParameters"      layout="${aspnet-request-routeparameters}" />
    </target>

    <!--${event-properties:item=EventId_Id} | ${uppercase:${level}} | ${logger} | ${message} ${exception:format=tostring} | url: ${aspnet-request-url} | action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}"-->
</targets>

<!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
<rules>
    <!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs (BlackHole) -->
    <logger name="System.*" finalMinLevel="Warn" />
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" finalMinLevel="Warn" />
    <!--Output hosting lifetime messages to console target for faster startup detection -->
    <logger name="Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime*" finalMinLevel="Info" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="${var:debugLogLevel}" writeTo="db,aiTarget" />
</rules>

appsettings.json:
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

As you can see in Program.cs, I am turning off logging when I'm running the API in debug mode. That part seems to be working. But, as mentioned, it's also logging handled exceptions, which I don't want. As an example, here is an action method in one of my controllers, where I'm handling an exception, and therefore don't want it logged, as it'll just clutter up the logs, when it was just bad user input:
// POST: api/Properties
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Property>> PostProperty(PropertyEditDto propertyDto)
{
    Property property = _mapper.Map<Property>(propertyDto);
    await _context.Properties.AddAsync(property);
    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        if (ex.InnerException.Message.StartsWith("Duplicate entry") && ex.InnerException.Message.EndsWith("'unit_UNIQUE'"))
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, $"The selected complex or scheme already has a unit number {property.UnitNumber}");
        }
    }
    return CreatedAtAction("GetProperty", new { id = property.Id }, prop);
}

The above causes the following exception to be logged:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
  ---> MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'unit_UNIQUE'
    at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ReceiveReplyAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 894
    at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs:line 37
    at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 130
    at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.NextResultAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 90
    at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.NextResultAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 49
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass30_0`2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

As a side note, I do not have any custom exception handler middleware.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I guess you could setup a middleware / exception-handler that is logging all unhandled exceptions to a special named logger (Redirect output from that special named logger to a target in NLog.config). When only  having a single logger that redirects output to NLog-target, then all other logger-output will be suppressed.

running the entire program in a try-catch block is a bad idea because it will have serious performance impact. you will need to stop doing that and switch to a global exception handler approach. here is the code I use personally:
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // show detailed exception information in development
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    // use custom exception handling in production
    app.UseExceptionHandler(appBuilder =>
    {
        appBuilder.Run(async context =>
        {
            var exceptionHandlerFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
            if (exceptionHandlerFeature != null)
            {
                var errorCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var exception = exceptionHandlerFeature.Error;

                #region try to get current user
                var userName = "Anonymous";
                if (context != null && context.User != null && context.User.Identity != null && context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    userName = context.User.Identity.Name;
                #endregion

                Log.Information("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                Log.Error(exception, "GLOBAL EXCEPTION HANDLED. Error Code: {ErrorCode}, User: {UserName}, Time: {Time}", errorCode, userName, DateTime.Now);

                // redirect to an error screen
                context.Response.Redirect("/error?errorCode=" + errorCode);
            }
        });
    });

    app.UseHsts();
}

By the way, when you do ´.UseNLog();´ you are not adding a service to the service container, you are registering a middleware (just wanted to clarify that because of the comment you wrote to that line). You shouldn't need to register a logger middleware when you use this approach.
For your reference, here is my Serilog configuration:
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.File(
        path: "Logs/log-.txt",
        rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
        retainedFileCountLimit: 10)
    .CreateLogger();

Log.Information("Server is starting... " + DateTime.Now.ToString());


I thought global exception handler is just a try-catch somewhere in the framework. What are those performance issues related to try-catch? Do you have a link that explains it?

encapsulating CreateHostBuilder in a try-catch block is not acceptable in any way. just because try-catch block exists and works doesn't mean we are supposed to run our entire program inside a try-catch block. an exception handler will handle errors in a "scope". what you are doing is something different, you are almost handling the entire program pretty much.

by the way, exception handler does not use a try-catch block. it looks at the HttpContext as the response is on its way to the client, and intervenes if an exception occurred in the scope. see here for how it works: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-8.0

you may need to adjust my code to make it work with your logger system but this is the proper way of handling exceptions in a web app. and if you dont want exception handler to intervene, you simply dont re-throw an exception in a catch block.
